# How to Know the key generated by push ()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an app in which I am using

```
mRef.push ().setValue (map);
```

Now I want to know the name of the key generated by this push command so that I can identify that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First store the key in local variable and then use the below code :-

```
String key = mref.push();                                              
mref.child(key).setValue(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you generate multiple keys and   while retrieving the data from Firebase database, you can use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(YOUR_PATH);

 ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Log.e("KEY",ds.getKey());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message
            Log.e("DB error", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    };
```